# Create li of all option selected with jquery

Tags: jquery, html-lists, html-select

I have multiple selects with multiples options and i would like to group every option selected in an ul..

I've try this => https://jsfiddle.net/Lvywpaq6/ but not working... :(

```
<select id="select1" class="my-select">
<optgroup label="None">
 <option>No thanks</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="1">
 <option>Test1</option>
 <option>Test2</option>
 <option>Test3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="2">
 <option>Test4</option>
 <option>Test5</option>
 <option>Test6</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="3">
 <option>Test7</option>
 <option>Test8</option>
 <option>Test9</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
<select id="select2" class="my-select">
<optgroup label="None">
 <option>No thanks</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="1">
 <option>Test1</option>
 <option>Test2</option>
 <option>Test3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="2">
 <option>Test4</option>
 <option>Test5</option>
 <option>Test6</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="3">
 <option>Test7</option>
 <option>Test8</option>
 <option>Test9</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
<div>
<ul class="my-ul"> </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to know how can I create a group of `li` with all of my selected option, dynamically ? And, btw, when I switch one option, I would like to update his `li`, not add another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Lvywpaq6/1/

```
$(function() {
  var $list = $('.my-ul');
  $('.my-select').change(function() {
      $list.empty();
      $("select.my-select option:selected").each(function() {
          var text = $(this).text();
          $('<li>').text(text).appendTo($list);
      });
  });
});
```

- Listen for the change events on all selects.
- Clear the list
- Add your LIs for each selection

If you only want to see selected options, test for "No thanks":

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Lvywpaq6/3/

If you want initial selections shown later, fire a `change` event at the end:

```
$(function() {
  var $list = $('.my-ul');
  $('.my-select').change(function() {
      $list.empty();
      $("select.my-select option:selected").each(function() {
          var text = $(this).text();
          if (text != "No thanks"){
              $('<li>').text(text).appendTo($list);
          }
      });
  }).change();
});
```

Comment: Great, thank you !! Is it possible to show only "li" when you select an option ? Show selected option and hide others..

Comment: Change `$("select.my-select option:selected")` to `$("option:selected", this)`

Comment: Yes, in this way i would like to show a list of "li" but only when every option is selected..

An example, at the beginning, "ul" is empty :
1/ You choose an option in first select : a "li" appears,
2/ You choose an option in the second select : another "li" appears,
3/ You decided to change one of your selected option, it change only his "li".

I'm not sur to be clear but i'm trying ^^

Thanks for your help, both of you !

Comment: You roxxxx Gone Coding !

Answer (score 0):

What you had was close.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvywpaq6/2/

> When I switch one option
>   Extract your update function into a separate function so it can be called on change and startup.

And add `.empty()` to clear previous results.

```
function update() {
    $(".my-ul").empty();
    $("select.my-select option:selected").each(function (){
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('<li>'+text+'</li>').appendTo('.my-ul');
  })
}

$(function() { 
    $("select").change(update)
    update(); 
});
```